# com.newrelic.agent.android: how to get rid of it?

Tags: uninstallation

Phone: Nexus 5
OS: 5.1.1

I have a lot of apps on my phone: probably 100+. A lot of them I use only once or twice a month.  I hooked up my phone to ADB recently and saw a ton of crashes, etc.  But what worried me most was New Relic.  I have 2 questions

1. How can I find out which app installed this New Relic Agent?
2. How can I uninstall the app?

[image: new_relic]

Comment: It's not an app, it's part of many apps.

Comment: Is there a way to find out which apps use it?